# Split a list partition (set of values) into multiple single value partitions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, split, partition

I have a table which is partitioned by list and each partition have multiple values. For example:

```
partition by list (COL1)
(
  partition GROUP_1 values ('VAL1','VAL2','VAL3')
)
```

This table has huge data and sometimes, multiple sessions are trying to access same block and I am facing read by other session problem. So, I am thinking of changing the structure to below:

```
Alter Table Table_1
Split Partition GROUP_1 INTO
  partition GROUP_2 values ('VAL1'),
  partition GROUP_3 values ('VAL2'),
  partition GROUP_4 values ('VAL3')
)  PARALLEL 5;
```

I cannot use DBMS_REDEF as it will cause object invalids. I am trying to use Split Partitions but I am getting ORA-14028.

What would be the best way of achieving this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found a recursive way of achieving this.

```
Alter Table Table_1
Split Partition GROUP_1 VALUES ('VAL1') INTO
  (partition GROUP_1,
  partition GROUP_2)  PARALLEL 5;
```

Then

```
Alter Table Table_1
Split Partition GROUP_2 VALUES ('VAL2') INTO
  (partition GROUP_2,
  partition GROUP_3)  PARALLEL 5;
```

This way, we create 3 different partition for 3 different value.

Is there any other faster way of doing this? Also, do you see any problems related to index or tablespace at all in the approach above? Thanks